# Python type hints for unpacking object

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to implement type hinting for object unpacking. Here is what I have currently

```
from typing import Tuple


class A:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: str):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def astuple(self) -> Tuple[int, str]:
        return self.x, self.y

    # Need to annotate the return type of __iter__
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.astuple())


a = A(1, "a")
# This cannot infer the type of x and y
x, y = a
reveal_type(x)
reveal_type(y)
# This infers the type of p and q as int and str respectively
p, q = a.astuple()
reveal_type(p)
reveal_type(q)
```

prints

```
$ mypy unpack_object.py
unpack_object.py:20: note: Revealed type is "Any"
unpack_object.py:21: note: Revealed type is "Any"
unpack_object.py:24: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
unpack_object.py:25: note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

However, I would like mypy to infer correct types for `x`, `y` (`int`, `str`). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You don't need to define `__next__`. `A` itself is not an iterator; it's just *iterable*. The iterator returned by `__iter__` iterates over the elements of the tuple returned by `A.get`.

Comment: If you *want* `A` to be an iterator, just have `__iter__` return `self`. In that case, it doesn't make much sense for `__next__` to return a *tuple*, though. I would think you'd want to return `self.x` on the first call, `self.y` on the second, and raise `StopIteration` thereafter.

Comment: The most sensible definition of `__iter__` might be `yield self.x; yield self.y`. But all of the above share a single problem: `__next__` doesn't have a fixed static return type. Iterators in the static typing model are homogenous; every call to `__next__` returns a value of the same type. You *could* say the return type is `str | int`, but that's not entirely accurate. It says that *any* value might be a `str` or an `int`, with no really way of knowing which it will be. Here, you *know* the first is a `str` and the second is an `int`.

Comment: @chepner I don't intend to have it as iterator. I just need correct types inferred by mypy on unpacking. Edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: I think what you want is to make `A` a subclass of `typing.NamedTuple`. As far as I know, `typing` doesn't provide a way to define a heterogeneous iterable type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to maintain type information when unpacking object attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69906075/1804173)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to define your own heterogeneous iterable type in Python. Make `A` a subclass of `NamedTuple` instead.

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class A(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: str


x, y = A(1, "a")
reveal_type(x)  # builtins.int
reveal_type(y)  # builtins.str
```

Comment: A note on generic fields: Unfortunately in Python 3.9+, [`NamedTuple` can no longer be generic](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88089), because multiple inheritance was prohibited, and therefore also inheritance from `Generic`. So if the fields of the class require some generics, `NamedTuple` is not a solution. I'm actually not sure if there exists _any_ solution for "type-safe heterogeneous unpacking" in combination with generics :/.